# What level has the most money in it?

Tags: ducktales-remastered

Now that I've finished the game, I want to buy all the collectables. To do this, I need a lot of money. In addition, I want to get the achievement for saving up $10 million. **What level is the most effective time/money wise for building up my riches?**